# iOS codesigning specs

Tags: ios, keychain, codesign

I want to create a tool for codesigning iOS apps on a linux server remotely.

I know codesign is oss but relies heavily on the keychain and is not as portable.

I know Adobe has a codesign utility for win and mac within flash that takes the provisioning profile, .p12, and .cer and signs the app.

UDK also does something similar but doesnt seem to need the .p12
( http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/AppleiOSProvisioning.html )

So my question is really, what is the process they are doing so i can recreate a tool that is cross platform that can do it.

Comment: Curious as to whether or not you found a solution to this.

Comment: This can only be done on OS X.

Comment: This is possible on other platforms and the signing itself is not very complicated once you know the steps. Example is UDK on windows can codesign apps.

Answer (score 8):

I've tried to work on this issue, and after a lot of sleepless nights, headaches, issues with keys and other stuff, I decided to stop bothering, bought a mac mini (fairly cheap), and installed it headless as a build machine. Works like a charm :)

I put a lot of work into the research and wasn't able to get it to work, so if someone does know the answer: greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

Try and have a look at this presentation: [Breaking iOS code signing](http://reverse.put.as/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/syscan11_breaking_ios_code_signing.pdf), which contains a lot of interesting information about the signing scheme.

I don't know anyway if the above presentation will give you the information you need.

Answer (score 3):

[Saurik created ldid](http://www.saurik.com/id/8), which is meant for code-signing on linux. It may be useful to checkout [this article](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode) about Developing without a Provisioning Profile and also [this project](https://github.com/rpetrich/ldid) which I believe is an ldid implementation.

If you have used the Adobe code signing utility before then you might have noticed that it is a bit flaky. I have had issues with it numerous times.

The truth is that it will be very hard to create a code-signing tool and even if you spent a ton of time on it and eventually got an implementation working, Apple could change any little piece of the code signing process that could end up breaking your entire system. It is better to rely on the tools that Apple has provided developers to do code signing. If I could make a suggestion it would be to NOT try to do this.