# Can I sign the iOS app with an AdHoc profile wihtout using XCode?

Tags: ios, ipa

Preferably using Linux, Windows is also OK.
Something like openssh and zip?

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: I do not like to go to office each time I need to start XCode. And I have MacMini in the office which only has XCode and serves the sole purpose to generate IPA. I would rather copy my dev certificate to my linux machine and just use some open tools. Any idea?

Comment: Can you shell in to the Mac? It should be possible to do this from the command line, but almost certainly not possible without a Mac.

Comment: Thanks for responding, this sounds promising. Now the Mac is behind firewall but, yes I could get it accessible, do you know by any change who to use shell for this? Because VNC is too slow.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/5301885/542425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can remotely shell into the Mac (ssh), then you should be able to build and sign your project from the command line. It may require some setup beforehand, but `xcodebuild` and `xcrun` should get you where you need to go. (This is the same kind of thing folks do to get automated continuous integration builds set up.)

Doesn't get you out of using Xcode or a Mac, but maybe gets you out of having to be physically sitting in front of that Mac to get work done.

Further reading:

- [Xcode “Build and Archive” from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line?rq=1)
- [`xcodebuild` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)
- [`xcrun` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcrun.1.html)

Comment: Also, while you'd still need a Mac, there do seem to be more CI things coming in Mavericks/Xcode 5: https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use TeamViewer ( payed version) or other remote desktop software to connect tom office mac mini. Otherwise you will break up the signing license too, beside it is hard to configure the keychain.

It will be very hard to figure out after you have signed a build why it doesn't install at client's PC, because no error messages there.